# UI issues in Spacemacs shell

Tags: shell, spacemacs

I'm using Spacemacs and multi-term on OS X 10.11. Preferred shell in zsh with oh-my-zsh installed.

In the Spacemacs shell window, there are two weird UI issues:

1. Command line never scrolls to the bottom, so that i always several empty lines in the bottom of the buffer.
2. Command prompt has got weird `4m` symbols prepended (**UPDATE:** per lunaryorn's comment, this got fixed by adding `export TERM=xterm-256color` to `.zshrc`. Previously `echo $TERM` yielded `eterm`).

Both issues are visible in the screenshot attached. Does anyone know how to address these?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You are right. Upvoting. Item #2 is fixed by the first comment to the question you've linked. Adjusting the question.

Comment: The empty lines sound like scroll margin. Can you check the value of the variable `scroll-margin` in the buffer?

Comment: @nanny - you're right, setting `(setq scroll-margin 0)` in config fixes the problem. Thanks!

Comment: There is also [this commit](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/pull/3546/files) that defines a `unset-scroll-margin` function, but i'm not sure how to invoke it from `.spacemacs`.